# Argument diagram (logic)

Tags: diagrams, logic

I need to diagram arguments (Beamer). I've tried to use tikzcd but it doesn't work. How can I draw a diagram as the following one?

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. Could you show us what you tried with `tikz-cd` (the code)? How didn't it work?

Answer (score 4):

You probably have a problem with `&`: when used in a `beamer` frame, `&` is not eligible for separating entries in a `tikz-cd` environment. You can use `\&` after telling it to `tikz`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzset{ampersand replacement=\&}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A diagram}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1em,column sep=1em]
{} \& {} \& 5 \arrow{d} \\
2 \arrow{dr} \& 3 \arrow{d} \& 4 \arrow{dl} \\
{} \& 1
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was faster than you on the [forum](http://www.guitex.org/home/it/forum/5-tex-e-latex/89543-diagrammi-ad-albero-per-logica#89563) ;)