# Diagramming logical arguments

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm having some issues drawing the following diagrams in LaTeX in an MLA formatted document. [I have gotten the diagrams in **box a** to work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141587/argument-diagram-logic), but I am having some issues lining up my premises in **box b**, because of the *therefore* sign - it is interpreted as math, so I can't add text next to it.

[image: logical argument]

edit:
My current code:
[image]

edit 2: 
Code

```
\begin{frame}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1em,column sep=1em]
{} \& 4\arrow{d} \\
2 \arrow{dr} \& 3 \arrow{d} \\
{} \& 1
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}

\end{frame}

or we could say:

\begin{flushleft}
\textit{a. Parents are complaining about religious mass in school} \\
\textit{b. Religion is important to study} \\
\therefore  \textit{Religion in school is a controversial, but hard subject to discuss}
\end{flushleft}
```

Comment: Edited it now. My apologies for not including the code.